# How can i print pdf file in Java Swing

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I want to like after click a JButton will directly pop out a printer window to print the pdf file no need to show the file, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do it ,

1. [You can get access to printers installed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jps/index.html), this requires how the printers are configured etc and then you require some [print plugin to write it to pdf file](http://www.pdf995.com/).
2. Else you can use [plenty of java pdf libraries available](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) to do the pdf creation part too

Answer (score 0):

See [Desktop.print(File)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#print%28java.io.File%29).